# Charles-Proxy Breakpoint

Tags: charles-proxy

I'm new to all this, trying to figure it out by doing, so please be kind :)

I have the breakpoint setup for `Charles Proxy`. My problem is, when I catch the input, it's not displaying the information like I see shown is this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dCHcdB8K0Lg

As you can see in the images, I only have `Overview` and `Edit Response` (which is blank).

[image: missing information, nothing shown]

Where as when I watch tutorials on this, they have: `Overview`, `Request`, `Response`, `Summary`, `Chart`, `Notes`, `Edit Response` and at the bottom the ability to select JSON Text to read/edit the information...

[image: At the top you have Responses and bottom you have JSON Text]

I cannot find any setting to fix this, but clearly I'm doing something wrong. Any idea why I cannot see or edit my information?

I've watched all tutorials I could find, but most seem a few years old. I've searched their own website for information and cannot find anything either.

Hoping to figure out what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: Which version of Charles-Proxy do you use? Note that on your screenshot you seem to have set a Break-Point on the request and not on the response. Therefore you won't see the data coming from the server because the request has not yet reached the server.

Comment: I'm using version 4.6.4 and I'm looking at the Breakpoint now. Response is checked, Request is not.